# Automapper Error mapping types only after publishing WCF server

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, wcf, automapper

I have a simple WCF service that is using AutoMapper (6.1.1.0) to map between Entity Framework models and DTO models to transmit down to our client app. We are new to AutoMapper.

We have been working on our development machines with the WCF service running in IIS Express locally and today I published the WCF service to an online server and configured it all up.  I can attach to the WCF SVC using the WCF Test Client and can get responses from methods available. Some of these methods use AutoMapper and others don't.

When I got to the 'main' function and tried to get a response I get the 'Error mapping types' error on one of the properties which is one of the DTO classes.

This is the parent class

```
[DataContract]
public class AgencyDetailDTO
{
    public AgencyDetailDTO()
    {
        credentials = new CredentialsDTO();
        son_blacklist = new List<SONBlacklistDTO>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string pcc { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string gds { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string default_currency { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool test { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public CredentialsDTO credentials { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<SONBlacklistDTO> son_blacklist { get; set; }
}
```

The error I get is

```
Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
agency_detail -> AgencyDetailDTO
ConfigWCFSA.agency_detail -> 
ConfigSharedModels.AgencyDetailDTO

Type Map configuration:
agency_detail -> AgencyDetailDTO
ConfigWCFSA.agency_detail -> 
ConfigSharedModels.AgencyDetailDTO

Property:
credentials
```

The 'credentials' is just made up of

```
[DataContract]
public class CredentialsDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public int agency_id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string cf_username { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string cf_password { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string cf_agent_id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string cf_booker_id { get; set; }
}
```

so nothing overly difficult, and if I tell AutoMapper to ignore the property it has no problem mapping all the other properties (there are many more Lists that I have left off the 'AgencyDetailDTO' class above to save space).

Like I say this all works perfectly on my development machine - it is just now its on a web server (Win Svr 2012 IIS 8) that we get this mapping issue.

I have created a Mapper config between all the various classes (and all the property names in the EF Models match those in my DTO, and I have used ReverseMap() where required so pretty sure I have all that correct

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
        {

            cfg.CreateMap<credentials, CredentialsDTO>().ReverseMap();                
            cfg.CreateMap<agency_detail, AgencyDetailDTO>().ReverseMap();
        });
```

Any ideas on what could be the root cause ?

Cheers
Paul

this is the full error from the WCF service (sorry for that)

```
Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
agency_detail -> AgencyDetailDTO
ConfigWCFSA.agency_detail -> 
ConfigSharedModels.AgencyDetailDTO

Type Map configuration:
agency_detail -> AgencyDetailDTO
ConfigWCFSA.agency_detail -> 
ConfigSharedModels.AgencyDetailDTO

Property:
credentials

Server stack trace: 
   at
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood
(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion 
version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at 
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply
(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at 
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at 
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService
(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage
(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke
(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IConfigService.GetAgencyConfiguration(String pcc, String gds)
   at ConfigServiceClient.GetAgencyConfiguration(String pcc, String gds)
```

as requested here is the EF generated agency_detail class

```
public partial class agency_detail
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public agency_detail()
    {
        this.son_blacklist = new HashSet<son_blacklist>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string pcc { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string gds { get; set; }
    public string default_currency { get; set; }
    public bool test { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<son_blacklist> son_blacklist { get; set; }

    public virtual credentials credentials { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There has got to be more error information. Please post a more complete error dump.

Comment: Well, my educated guess is that the service might not be returning this field. Double-check the service definition.

Comment: The service reference might be outdated.

Comment: So it looks like the error happens at the server side, but it's been reported on the client side, correct?

Comment: Yes the error is happening in the WCF code on the server.  The error is returned to the WCF test client (the one built into Visual Studio) that is attached to the WCF SVC.

Comment: You are going to need to gather error information from the server. You will find more details as to why it's failing there.

Comment: Alternatively, you can return more error information on the response itself, but only for troubleshooting and then remove it. You are already exposing way more internal information than you should by your service returning error information back to the client like it is now.

Comment: I turned on the <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" /> on the SVC when the error first occurred so that information would come back to me for debug

Comment: Couple of things: 1) I would use profiles and looks through and add those profiles when you wire up your mapper  2) Why are you not mapping type to type?  CreateMap<SomeObject, AnotherObject>() 3) If you don't need the reverse map remove it. 4) You may have an issue with the constructor newing up the credentials prop....Other than that, I am just guessing until I have more code....cheers

Comment: I see. Still, you should do your best to prevent unhandled exceptions in services. Always catch it on the server side, log it and return a response that indicates failure. You will need to add this on the server side to figure out what is going on. There simply isn't enough information. Are you able to share the code for `ConfigWCFSA.agency_detail`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after several hours debugging this we found the answer !  The database had two columns switched on for 'always encrypted' on the credentials table - however the live server didn't have the correct key to decrypt them (as it was created on a different machine).

So the problem wasn't with AutoMapper it was 'further up the stack' and after attaching some remote debuggers we finally managed to work our way back to the original culprit.

Thanks all for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with CredentialsDTO and a difference between the dev and the prod machine.

Start With which dll contains CredentialsDTO, problem could be:

- It is in it's own dll, and there is a problem With Access to this dll, or there is an old Version of this dll on the prod server
- The prod machine has a copy of CredentialsDTO in the GAC that is different from latest version

I would start With renaming CredentialsDTO and credentials and then redeploy.